# date minus date and take difference

Tags: php, date

**Example :**

- I have contract start date : 2013-05-03 (YYYY-MM-DD)
- And contract end date : 2014-08-03 (YYYY-MM-DD)

**Question :**

- How to get difference between this two date in MONTHS (example 15 months) ?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @AndyHolmes Nothing, i don't know from where to start this, tanks

Comment: I would suggest trying something yourself first, then ask us for help when you get stuck. There's lots of info out there on how to do this stuff :)

Comment: @NebojsaSapic: izvoli :) [demo](https://eval.in/208059)

Comment: @Glavić Zahvaljujem! :)